# Does Windows 8.1 filter spoofed packets, or packets with bad checksums?

Tags: windows, networking, packet, security-policy

I recently started a software security class. I expect to be required to craft and send packets; yet I read somewhere my Windows 8.1 installation filters packets based on a valid checksum. Is this claim true? Are there any other restrictions not found on a "standard" Linux distribution (such as Debian)? If any of these restrictions exist, can they be circumvented, and at what cost?

Comment: You should be able to test and confirm whether Windows Firewall does filter such packets or not. As for disabling such restrictions, turning off the firewall should accomplish just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not windows 8.1, or other OS's feature. Checksum verification built in layer2 and layer3 headers format